# Django add recipe form

Tags: django, python-3.x

I hope you will give me some advice.
So I can't save Recipe into my database through RecipeCreateForm.

Here is my code:
models.py

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='recipes_created')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='recipes/%Y/%m/%d')
    description = models.TextField("Description")
    ingredients = models.TextField("Ingredients")
    preparation = models.TextField("Preparation")
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Recipe

class RecipeCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = ('title', 'image' 'description', 'ingredients', 'preparation')
```

Comment: Are you adding a new object or want to edit existing object?I could not get what are you asking for.

Comment: Are you getting any error in running this code? Is your recipe_form valid?

Comment: Do you have any outstanding migrations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing an ',' in the forms between 'image' and 'description

This is why the error is 'imagedescription',  it is reading both of them as 1 string.

```
fields = ('title', 'image' 'description', 'ingredients', 'preparation')
```

with the ',' it will read

```
 fields = ('title', 'image', 'description', 'ingredients', 'preparation')
```

Comment: you can put in .....eg......image = models.ImageField(upload_to='recipes/%Y/%m/%d', required=False.)......... or indeed on any item that is not required.. if this is not what you want then i suggest you create another question.. feel free to link me n here and i will have a look

Comment: I can but please post a new question and put the link to that question here. This is not a good way to discuss this..

Comment: Can you provide a link please

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a view in views.py file. To create a new object, view will be as shown:

```
def recipe_create(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = RecipeCreateForm(request.POST)
        new_recipe = form.save()   #create a new instance in model form
    else:
        form = RecipeCreateForm()
    context = {'form':form}
    template = 'xyz.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

If request is post i.e you are saving data from the form to database. And if request is get you are rendering an empty form.

Comment: If you have already created the view you should add this view to your question so that others can understand it properly.